# What are the ways to keep a value available globally on React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, global-variables

So, I am making an application on react-native. People login and then they can move around, however, the login value will be used many times through the story. I am currently sending the id as parameter during movement time after time, which is not very efficient, as not every screen uses it. What is the best way to keep it available across the application, since I was told that global variables and singletons are dangerous to use.

Comment: Use the context api: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html this improves over globals by ensuring the components where you access that context explicitly require them and it avoids global namespace collisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Redux** is perfectly designed for that.
It offers a global state for your application, that every component can access through their props.

You can store access token, user infos, and many other variable in it.